# Airtable Python Wrapper documentation problem while using it online

Tags: python, wrapper, airtable

I have a problem using Airtable module for python
While I'm using my IDE in my local computer the documentation works fine but when I use the same code on any site like repl.it or host it on pythonanywhere it gives me errors
some  attributes I found it's replacement such as insert will be create, get_all will be get...etc, but I couldn't find a replacement for the argument 'sort' which is used in get_all attribute, and that makes my code unable to work as I want it to work

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're using the same version of Airtable in all of the places where you're trying to run it.

Comment: it's the same version but I think the problem is that my machine runs by windows but the sites like repl.it is running by linux or macOs I don't know what should I do now